# Python - memory profiler - how to find the peak?

Tags: python

I'm using the [memory profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) on my python program and I got these results:

```
439    426.6 MiB -27645.5 MiB         166    
445    381.3 MiB -27932.1 MiB         166    
446    241.1 MiB -24899.4 MiB         166    
448    241.1 MiB -11994.2 MiB         166      
452    262.4 MiB -22833030.3 MiB      316021     
454    262.4 MiB -68466205.7 MiB      947565      
455    262.4 MiB -45644210.9 MiB      631710     
458    262.4 MiB -22822046.2 MiB      315855      
463    262.4 MiB -22820973.9 MiB      315855      
466    262.4 MiB -22820973.8 MiB      315855      
469    262.4 MiB -22820973.1 MiB      315855              
472    262.4 MiB -13851.5 MiB         166
```

What exactly the big numbers mean? why is it negative? I don't see any change related to the 1st column (241 MiB etc.)
I.e. - If I divide 68466205.7 / 947565 = ~70 MiB - what does it mean?

My purpose is to find the peak in the memory so I'll know where the majority of the RAM goes during a single iteration.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) -> **Output will follow**

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
```

> The third column (Increment) represents the difference in memory of the current line with respect to the last one.

Lastly, It will depend on your settings...

Comment: I read it already - but it doesn't make sense - 1. how come it is always negative? (the code here is partial, but there is not positive  Increment in the whole code.  2. how come in lines 448 - 452 there is a negative value but the mem usage increased..? (the missing lines are n lines and comments)